# JavaScript - Speed of the animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

what does this code do is it shuffles random characters for 4.5 seconds then it will display the text in the

tag. But the problem is when its shuffling random_char characters its animating too fast how can i slow the animation speed of the random characters thats being displayed until the actual text displayed.

```
<p class="home-page-subtitle shuffle is-main">Web Developer</p>

        const random_char = () => {
        const possible = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";
        return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      };
      
      const mask = (chars, progress) => {
        const masked = [];
      
        for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
          const position = (i + 1) / chars.length;
          if (position > progress) {
            masked.push(random_char());
          } else {
            masked.push(chars[i]);
          }
        }
      
        return masked.join('');
      };
      
      const shuffle = el => {
        const chars = el.textContent.split('');
      
        const params = {
          progress: 0 };
      
      
        const a = anime({
          targets: params,
          progress: 1,
          duration: 4500,
          easing: 'easeInQuad',
          update: () => {
            el.textContent = mask(chars, params.progress);
          },
          complete: () => {
            el.classList.add('completed');
          } });
      
      
        el.onclick = () => {
          el.classList.remove('completed');
          a.restart();
        };
      };
      
      for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('.shuffle')) {
        shuffle(el);
      }
```

Comment: The code you have posted references a function called `anime()`, but you have not included the code for that function. Ideally we need code we can run which demonstrates the problem, but we can't run this code without that function.